# How does a node forget about other nodes?

Tags: address, nodes, peer-discovery

It is said that *addr message: Provide information on known nodes of the network. Non-advertised nodes should be forgotten after typically 3 hours.*

I did not totally understood what does it mean forgetting a node? A node has a list of peers, and it is checking every 3 hours if these peer are active? Does it work like this? How does this forgetting mechanism work?

Comment: Where did you read this?

Comment: I read it here: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_documentation#addr

Comment: Ignore that wiki, it was inaccurate when most of it was written years ago, and has been unmaintained since, mostly. I suggest using the bitcoin.org developer documentation instead.

Comment: OK. So does it mean that there is no neighbour forgetting if it does not respond in 3 hours or something like that? The answer to my question is still missing.

Comment: I'll write a full answer too when I have time; this is just a short comment to let you know the premise makes little sense.

Comment: OK. I am waiting for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for a node to "forget" a node. This is not something that is required nor necessary. What Bitcoin Core does in response to a `getaddr` message (so it sends an `addr` message) is that it checks its list of nodes. It filters through that list for the things that it recently had a connection to and that it didn't have multiple failed connections to before. There is no checking that a node is actually live and it doesn't do it on a set timer either.

Comment: But isn't there a number limit for the connections? Doesn't a node try to find another connection if one of its connection has failed?

Comment: Yes, so? That doesn't prevent a node from remembering that it recently connected to someone or that it recently tried to connect to a node and failed. And that only pertains to outgoing connections. If an incoming connection drops, Core doesn't care. It will only try to fill all of the 8 outbound connection slots.

Comment: So the limit for outbound connections is 8, right?